# Relabelling multiple columns label attribute without a for loop

Tags: r, attributes

I manage to create the attribute label for determined variables in a dataset, but I used a loop. I would like to avoid using a loop, can you help me?

Here is a toy example with the iris dataset.

Let´s suppose I want to add an attribute label to the "Sepal.length", "Petal.width", and "Species" variables. What I did was the following:

1) created a vector with the name of the variables I want to add the attribute to.

```
varNames <- c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species")
```

2) created a character vector with the labels I want to add

```
newLabels <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

3) Then, created a for loop to do the task of assigning attribute labels to 
the selected variables.

```
for (i in 1:length(varNames)) {
attributes(iris[[which(names(iris) %in% varNames[i])]])$label <-  
newLabels[i]
}
```

How can I do this without a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it by finding columns that you want to append "a","b" and "c" and using %in%, and append the appropriate tag.

```
# Your vector
  varNames <- c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species")
# Use names() to append
  names(newLabels) <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

Code to append appropriate tag

```
names(iris)[names(iris) %in% varNames] <- paste(names(iris)[names(iris) %in% varNames], names(newLabels), sep = ".")

# And output
> names(iris)
[1] "Sepal.Length.a" "Sepal.Width"    "Petal.Length"   "Petal.Width.b"  "Species.c"
```

**UPDATED POST**

I you want to change the atrribute label of the iris variables than you can achieve this by using `lapply` and `label` like this

```
  varNames = c(Sepal.Length="a", Petal.Width="b",Species="c")
    
  # Apply to each value of varNames 
  label(iris[c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species")]) = lapply(names(varNames), 
                          function(x) label(iris[,x]) = varNames[x])
```

And the output

```
> attributes(iris$Sepal.Length)$label
Sepal.Length 
         "a" 
> attributes(iris$Petal.Width)$label
Petal.Width 
        "b" 
> attributes(iris$Species)$label
Species 
    "c"
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Miha, though what i want to change is the atrribute label of the iris variables, not to add the `newLabels` at the end of their names. If you look at the attributes label of the `iris` columns, they are NULL (e.g `attributes(iris$Sepal.Length)$label` ). Nonetheless, maybe I can achieve that from the idea in your code, I´ll have to check.

Comment: @csmontt I've updated my post. Please see if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will not work on built in datasets like iris and you will have to modify the data-frame name in the function code for every data-frame you're using this on...
That being said, on a normal data-frame like for example this one:

```
dta=data.frame(SL=c(1,2,3,4,5),SW=c(6,7,8,9,10),PL=c(11,12,13,14,15),PW=c(16,17,18,19,20),Spe=c("f","g","h","i","j"))
```

with similar additional information:

```
varNames <- c("SL", "PW", "Spe")
newLabels <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

this is a way to do it without loop:

```
fu=function(i){  
attributes(dta[[which(names(dta) %in% varNames[i])]])$label <<- newLabels[i]
}
mapply(fu,1:length(varNames))
```

verify first label:

```
> attributes(dta[[1]])$label
[1] "a"
```